# FabricJS Vertical Text Positioning inside Text box

Tags: fabricjs

I am having an issue where depending on the text length and size the text itself is positioned vertically in different areas.
My problem is then I am replicating this functionality in PHP to be able to generate a PNG and I cant see the logic behind why text gets positioned the way it does.
Here are a few screen shot examples.
Short Text, Large Font, tall box, Text is positioned further down inside the box:

[image]

Longer Text, smaller font, same tall box, Text is positioned at the very top of the box:
[image]

ideally I would like figure out the logic behind this so I can reproduce pixel for pixel what it is doing in PHP as this would solve any legacy bugs as well. Alternatively, being able to set it so text was always centered or top vertically aligned would be acceptable.

Thank you for any help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behaviour.  What you are seeing is the ascent and the descent of the font.  Mathematically the gap at the top of the text will match the difference in font size, ie: 20pt font with 5pt descent will be a 25pt descent with a 100pt font.

Comment: So its basically built into the font and not something I can calculate? That makes a lot more sense than where I was heading. I got close to getting my PHP code to match by changing my valign to top. However, it looks like it is still a little off in some scenarios. I am now thinking either the font descent is not the same between fabricjs and PHP. OR fabric JS is using a different valign setting. OR is because fabricjs uses textBaseline of alphabetic.

Comment: Any of your theories can be correct, PHP would likely use a truetype font and fabric will be using a webfont.  technically the same but not always.  There are font measuring functions build into the Fabric api, you would need to dig into it and find them though.  As opposed to trying to center the text inside its own bounding box, you are likely better off to recenter this entire object based on a background box.